# Possibility of build Length index vector without having length information at compile time

Tags: haskell, types, static-typing

So this is length index vector:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving Show
type One = S Z
type Two = S One
type Three = S Two

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
  Nil  :: Vec Z a
  (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

I am thinking how can I construct value of this vector from list

`t :: [a] -> Vec n a` -- but I don't know n at compile time, does it Z or S Z or so on..

So I can add extra param which have info about length of a vector:

```
fromList' :: SNat n -> [a] -> Maybe (Vec n a)
fromList' (SS n) (x:xs) = (x :>) <$> fromList' n xs
fromList' SZ [] = return Nil
fromList' _ _ = Nothing

data SNat (n :: Nat) where
  SZ :: SNat Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)

class KNat (n :: Nat) where kNat :: SNat n
instance KNat Z where kNat = SZ
instance KNat n => KNat (S n) where kNat = SS kNat
```

Now I can run in repl explicitly providing desired length:

```
fromList' (SS (SS (SZ))) [1,2]
```

Just 1:>2:>Nil

I can do so:

```
fromList :: KNat n => [a] -> Maybe (Vec n a)
fromList = fromList' kNat
```

But now to run this I **must provide length info explicitly again in type signature**:

```
fromList [1,2] :: Maybe (Vec Two Int)
```

Is it true that I can't rid from this extra param (or fixed type signature) carrying type length info in the source file, or another words this **length info should be anyway some how fixed statically in my source file**, and there is **no way** to extract this information from list itself (just with t :: [a] -> Vec n a) ? (because there is no types constructed at runtime and Vec type must be fixed statically before runtime starts)

Is my understanding of this situation correct?

So for example if I get lists data from user input (IO) and I expect that length of this lists must be for example only 1,2,3,4,5, the Vec type **dictate to me** do 5 case brunches for every length:

```
case (length l)
 of 1 -> dosomething1 $ fromList' (SS (SZ)) l 
 of 2 -> dosomething2 $ fromList' (SS (SS (SZ))) l
 of 3 -> dosomething3 $ fromList' (SS (SS (SS (SZ)))) l
 of 4 -> dosomething4 $ fromList' (SS (SS (SS (SS (SZ))))) l
 of 5 -> dosomething5 $ fromList' (SS (SS (SS (SS (SS (SZ)))))) l
 _ -> showError "Ops"

-- After a lot of python programming my intuition leads me to just :)
-- dosomething $ fromList l
```

So I guess then I lift more info (as length in this example) to type level, type system will dictate to me pay more explicit specific static info providing?

Comment: If you don't know the length, what are you getting out of having a Vec instead of a List?

Comment: @LouisWasserman It's entirely possible to do computations where the types keep track of *relationships* between lengths and benefit from that, even when the actual original length is unknown. e.g. I've written a grid puzzle solver that worked by splitting rows & columns into a branching tree of fragments. The solver works on any size of puzzle, so I don't know the lengths, but the types force me to do operations that keep the fragments adding up to the original (unknown) length, on all branches of the tree.